# How to get DI working with Guice and Webapps?

Tags: java, web-applications, dependency-injection, guice

How do you get DI to work in a webapp?  So far I've done the following:

1) Annotate setter method with `@Inject`

2) Extend `AbstractModule` so that it binds the interface class to the implementation class for the attribute whose setter was annotated in step 1

3) Extend `GuiceContextServletListener` and overrode getInjector so that it returns `Guice.createInjector(new ExtendedAbstractModule())`

4) Registered the extended `GuiceContextServletListener` in `web.xml` as a listener

I've verified that the extended `GuiceContextServletListener.getInjector()` method is called when the webapp is started.  The attribute whose setter was annotated is not being injected and remains `null`.

Comment: How do you get the instance of the object whose attribute needs to be injected? Do you instantiate it using `new`?

Comment: Yes I am instantiating the object using new.  The object is instantiated within a servlet that is configured in web.xml as opposed to binding through guice.

Answer (score 0):

What annotation are are you using on the setter?

I normally use @Named annotation to get attribute values which can be pointed to a property file or setup individually.

http://code.google.com/p/google-guice/wiki/BindingAnnotations

@Inject

void somethingSetter(@Named('Tag')String s) {

}

There is a tutorial of how to setup a complete Java web service using Guice and Sitebricks here:
http://www.techtraits.ca/five-minute-guide-to-setting-up-a-java-webserver/

Comment: I am only using the @Inject annotation.  I have likewise tried using @Inject with the @Named annotation and changed my binding to bind to the annotated name.

Answer (score 0):

I went ahead and created a `ServletModule` that serves the servlet that instantiates the object with the `@Inject` setter.  After instantiating the object I get the `Injector` from the `ServletContext` and call the `injectMembers` method passing it the instantiated object.